# How do you describe the feeling you get when you've almost dropped something but caught it in time?

Tags: phrases

Question says it all.

I've had suggestions of using "relieved" or "elated", but none of them really sound like what I'm thinking of.  Think about it this way.  The other day, I nearly dropped my laptop while walking to class.  My laptop is really, really, pricey, and dropping it would render it into a nice little paperweight.

Luckily though, I caught it just as it was fumbling around in my hands.

I don't know what to describe it as.

Comment: Perhaps relief?

Comment: Has to be relief, cant think of any-other emotion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's best to use two words here. On the one hand, you're relieved by the fact that nothing bad ultimately happened; on the other hand, you're harrowed (or some other word) by the idea of what could have happened. "*Harrowed but relieved*, I …"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a mixture of emotions were present, and that's why a single word doesn't fit.

Relief is a very common reaction to the sudden freedom from a strong fear and anticipation of something bad; a swell of relief, mixed with overwhelming gratitude, as well as a little bit of chagrin (feeling distressed or humiliated).

That's what I feel when this happens, even if I'm alone.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of *A rush of adrenaline* or *pumped* ?

Answer (score -1):

I would describe it as "a sudden rush of adrenaline which then leads to shock and then rising relief".

Comment: FWIW in reality, the shock comes first, which produces the adrenaline ;)